# Removing element keeps element in (re)calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a simple application that calculates the total price of all the rows in a table.

New rows get added like this:

```
    function add() {

        [...data removed for readability...]    

          jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: {
                            a:'addadminprice',
                            id:<? echo $id; ?>,
                            priceid:el.attr('value'),
                            price:price

                        }, 
                        url: options.actionurl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(result){
                         if (result.status=='success') {
                            var initaddprice = 0;
                            var row="<tr class='pricedata' rel='"+result.id+"'>";
                            row+="<td class='drag'>::::</td>";
                            row+="<td>"+el.text()+"</td>";
                            row+="<td class='right'>"+price+"</td>";
                            row+="<td><input type='text' onchange='recalc(this,"+result.id+")' value='"+price+"' /></td>";
                            row+="<td>"+(el.data('percent')=='1'?"%":"")+"</td>";
                            row+="<td><input type='text' onchange='recalc(this,"+result.id+")' value='"+result.qty+"' /></td>";
                            row+="<td class='right'>"+initaddprice.toFixed(3)+"</td>";
                            row+="<td><a class='button' href='#' onclick='return removeprice(this,"+result.id+")'>remove</a></td>";     
                            row+="</tr>";
                            var isfound=false;
                            $('.pricedata').last().after($(row));
                            el.remove();
                            changePrice();
                            recalcall();
                            setsort();
                            saveposition();
                         }
        }
    });
```

As you can see it adds the row - then recalculates the total based all the rows. So far so good, it works fine.

```
    function recalcall() {
        console.clear();
        console.log('----start calculation----');
        var total=0;
        $('.pricedata').each(function(){
            var price=parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(6).text());
            if (isNaN(price)) price=0;
            total+=price;
            console.log('+'+price+' = '+total);
        });
        console.log('----end calculation----');
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(3));
    }
```

When I remove one row, it removes the element and will recalculate the total again. But unfortunately the row is still included in the calculation process? I'm at loss here. Once you remove an element, it should be taken in consideration, right?

```
    function removeprice(el,id) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
         jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: {
                            a:'deleteprojectprice',
                            id:id
                        }, 
                        url: options.actionurl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(result){
                         if (result.status=='success') {                            
                            $(el).closest('tr').remove();
                         }
            }
            });

        }

        recalcall();        
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to ask for result.status, when you are alreday in the success function. The fact that it is success is how you got into that callback function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `removeprice` function, move `recalcall();` in to the success function

```
success: function(result){
if (result.status=='success') {                            
  $(el).closest('tr').remove();
   recalcall(); // call function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like following

```
function removeprice(el,id) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
         jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: {
                            a:'deleteprojectprice',
                            id:id
                        }, 
                        url: options.actionurl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(result){
                         if (result.status=='success') {                            
                            $(el).closest('tr').remove();
                         } 

                           //have this here
                           recalcall(); 

            }
            });

        }


    }
```